# Unable to call request in SoapUI - Ambiguous method overloading

Tags: xml, soap, groovy, soapui

I use following code in `SoapUI` SOAP request as a `Script Assertion` to get value from xml output:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder

def xml = new com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder(context.response)
def fname = xml.getNodeValue("//*:name")
```

It is working well, when I execute request directly, but get error message when call it from another test step with this code: `testStepgetAttachment.run(testRunner, context)`

Error message:

> Ambiguous method overloading for method
>   com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder#. Cannot resolve which
>   method to invoke for [null] due to overlapping prototypes between:
>     [interface org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject]   [interface
>   org.w3c.dom.Node]

Comment: `context.response` is null, so Groovy doesn't know which method to call...

Comment: @tim_yates : I see, but it is working when I execute directly that SOAP request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Context is not simply Context. It depends on what you are doing.

If I run it directly - either as a teststep, testcase or testsuite - it is an instance of `com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestRunContext`

If I run it from a Groovy Script teststep in another testcase, it is an instance of `com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.support.MockTestRunContext`

And there are probably more possibilities.

Comment: How could I handle these different scenarios in Groovy script?

Comment: I think you will need to fetch the response directly from the teststep, and not via the context. You could do it in Groovy Script with something like testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("TestStepName").getPropertyValue("response")

Comment: Ahhh. You already have a variable testStepgetAttachment containing the teststep instance. Then you should be able to do a testStepgetAttachment.getPropertyValue("response") after you have finished the run()